# How to find out if a cell is (visibly) blank in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice, spreadsheet

In LibreOffice Calc the `=BLANK()` formula will only return `TRUE` on cells with the underlying datatype ”blank”. In other words: If the cell contains a formula that returns nothing (or if it contains the empty text string), `=BLANK()` will be `FALSE`. Is there a way to check if a cell contains displayable content, such as a text string or a number?

In the screenshot below, the `=ISBLANK(B3)` formula in `C3` returns `FALSE`, as the cell contains a formula returning nothing. How would I go about to check is a B:B cell is ”blank” in the sense of not containing any data?

[image: Image showing a ”blank” field not trigegring ISBLANK]

Comment: Hmm - with `=""` in F2 (providing an empty string as lookup value for `b`) and `=LEN(B3)=0` in C3, you could check if cell B2 has an empty string as content. But i fear this is just a dirty workaround...

Comment: @tohuwawohu That's a clever hack! (Though one I'd prefer not to have to maintain over time...)

Comment: @tohuwawohu Until the `ISBLANK` is extended to include empty strings, I wouldn't call that a workaround but a solution. Combine the tests with logical "or" and that's it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are different ways to work around the limitations of `ISBLANK()`:

- As described in my comment, you may provide explicitly an empty string as lookup value in Column `F` for "b" (with `=""` in `F2`), so you can test the LEN() of B's content.
- Another option would be to "extract" the value of the `B` column's cells using the **[CELL()](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060104.html#bm_id3155509)** function together with the "Contents" InfoType, and check the result. If cell `F2`  (lookup value for "b") is empty, `=CELL("CONTENTS"; B3)` returns "0". The following formula returns TRUE for `B3` and `B4`. If all your lookup values are either empty or `!=0`, you could use the following function in col `C` to check for empty results without modifying your lookup table:

  > =(CELL("CONTENTS";B1)= 0)

While the first solution requires editing your lookup table, the second works "out of the box", but it assumes that there's no "0" lookup value.

Comment: `=""`, `=LEN(B3)=0` and `=CELL("CONTENTS";B3)` almost work, but if the source cell contains a space character this is 'visibly' blank, but yet it returns false unexpectedly.

Answer (score 2):

If the cell is empty, or has one or more blanks (so is not 'visible'), then you might want to use this instead to test it instead of simply `=LEN(B3)=0`:

```
=len(trim(b3))=0
```